# Tile service from local tile images

Tags: tiles, image-service

I have a pre-tiled image for some area, that

- Tiles are in JPG format.
- Tiles do not overlap.
- Each tile has its own world file.
- All tiles have the same projection.

Now, I want to consume those tiles as a tile service,

1. Is there any way to make such service without making a mosaic, i.e. tile service from the tile images immediately.
2. Should my tiles follow some scheme standard for naming and storage directory structure.
3. I prefer a solution based on ESRI/ArcGIS technologies, but any other solution will be useful.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but you could dynamically create the tiles from a fixed image. It's slower, but workable, especially if you want to apply smoothing after zooming.

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamically create the tiles`; My question in other words: what changes I have to make on my tiles to be ready for publishing a tile service by a known commercial or open source product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use standard tiling schemes like XYZ (Google) or TMS or ESRI Cache. Take your source images (not the tiles you made) and run it through gdal_translate.exe to produce an mbtiles or geopackage which are sqlite databases. Then you can use gdaladdo to add overviews/zoom levels. Otherwise use a python library like gdal2tiles_parallel.py or the original non parallel version.

Comment: Thank you, it's a useful start point for me, actually, my source images are the tiles themselves, they are produced through a complex analyzing process, so, I can rename them or organize them in respect to any recommended scheme, but I'm trying to avoid generating a mosaic image then re-tile them.

Comment: if your tiles can be read as geospatial raster data then use gdaltindex to create an index shapefile.  then possibly use gdalretile.  Not sure maybe you can create a VRT from your tiles and then run gdal2tiles_parallel.py to create TMS tiles.  Then use mbutil or landez python scripts to generate an mbtiles or tiles2gpkg_parallel.py if you want a geopackage.

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html  -if you can build a VRT then you are golden you won't need to mosaic them into one image.

Comment: if you do need to stitch them together you may want to try https://github.com/mapbox/untiler

Comment: another option is you maybe able to create a tile provider for leaflet that's based on your custom tiles. http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html  https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1020